# How to properly check if a string is in an element of tuple in python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple like this tuple1 = ('xdxdx asrsd', 'opopo gdgd', 'wdfsd dsds', 'sdfsaf dsjhd ds')

I want to check if the string1 = 'op' is in one of the element of the tuple.

So I want to write a statement like this :

```
if string1 in in tuple1:
     print True
```

Obviously, this statement doesn't work, here is my attampt so far:

```
for i in tuple1:
     if string1 in i:
         print True
         break
     else:
         print False
```

However, this code does not work because I will get error saying argument of type 'int' is not iterable.

If I try:

```
for i in tuple1:
     if string1 in tuple1[i]:
         print True
         break
     else:
         print False
```

I will get another error saying TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str.

So, can anyone teach me how to properly check if a string is in an element of a tuple in python?

Thank you.

Update: Sorry I think I messed something up, I double checked my code and the actual tuple in my code is not composed with string but something else, I have to go through subprocess module to check it out but sorry for wasting your time....

Update2: I cast tuple1 to string and the first attempt worked, thanks for help.

Comment: _"I will get error saying argument of type 'int' is not iterable."_. That is not the error I get. I get `NameError: name 'false' is not defined`. Please post the code that actually gave you the error you're describing.

Comment: You might want to double-check your first attempt. You shouldn't be getting any such errors with that code and the values of `tuple1` and `string1` shown.

Comment: @Kevin , sorry it should be True and False not true and false, fixed.

Comment: Your second try works for me as well. Maybe you got an error not related with those bits of code.

Comment: Now I am not getting an error at all. It prints False and then True and then completes with no exception being raised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `any` function in place of a nested loop.

```
print any(string1 in value for value in tuple1)
```

Comment: what is the difference of `print any(string1 in value for value in tuple1)` and `print [string1 in value for value in tuple1][0]`

Comment: Well, your list comprehension is just a long way of writing `print string1 in tuple1[0]`, but I think you are referring to the use of the generator expression as the argument to `any`. Since `any` can exit as soon as it finds the first string, you don't need to check if `string1` is a substring of *all* the elements. With the generator expression, you'll stop iterating over `tuple1` as soon as a match is found, instead of building a full list of `True` and `False` value that you don't need.

Comment: Ah i see, so any is not applied after the parenthesis term is fully evaluated? This is the reason i asked. Thanks

Comment: Not quite. With `any(string1 in value for value in tuple1)`, if the first element of `tuple1` contains `string1`, then the first check succeeds and `any` returns `True`. You never need to look at the rest of `tuple1`, because the generator only looks at a value from `tuple1` when `any` requests a value from the generator. With `any([string1 in value for value in tuple1])`, by contrast, a full list of `True`s and `False`s is created before `any` is actually called.

Answer (score 2):

```
for sentence in tuple1:
    for word in sentence:
        if string1 in word:
            print 'True'
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast the tuple to a list, then iterate?

```
tup=('foo','bar')

for i in list(tup):
    print i
```

Also, your TypeError is caused by trying to index via a string. What you're calling is basically `tup['hi']`, which works for dictionaries, but not tuples. You can just call `if string1 in i`.